# why the realloc() return NULL when I repeatlly call it l 30 times?

Tags: c, memory-management

I want to combine two buffer as one

```
int BBB(char *dest,int sz,char *sour,int s_sz)
{
   if((dest=realloc(dest,sz+s_sz))==NULL)//
   {
       perror("realloc");
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < s_sz; i++)
   {
       *(dest + sz +i)=*(sour+i);
   }
   return sz+s_sz ;
}
```

The above code worked well on combine small buff,But when i repeatedly call that  the error

```
:malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff8cf009800: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
```

is returned, 
the debug info

```
dest:0x0000000103008200 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nBdpagetype:...
sz:33792
s_sz:1024
```

below is my main function .

```
 do{
     r_n=recv(sfd,rbuff,BUFSIZ,0);
     BBB(rdata,nbuff,rbuff,BUFSIZ);
     memset(rbuff,0,BUFSIZ);
     nbuff+=BUFSIZ;
   } while (r_n);
```

thanks bro , so I want to know how to fix it ?

Comment: `dest=realloc` That changes a **local** variable. It does not change the caller's `rdata` variable. So every time `realloc` is called it gets the same value for the first parameter. Which can break at any time as `realloc` can (and often does) return a different value for the newly allocated memory.

Comment: You are _leaking_ memory. You do `realloc` in the function on `dest` but `dest` is _never_ propagated back to caller. So, the second time you call the function it's exactly the same as the first _except_, on each loop iteration you allocate a new/disjoint buffer instead of adjusting the size of the "current" existing buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a successful call to `realloc` with a given non-null pointer value, you are not allowed to keep using that pointer value passed to `realloc`. You need to instead use the value returned by `realloc`.

You are assigning the return value from `realloc` to the *local* variable `dest`, so in the calling code, `rdata` will remain unchanged.

So depending on whether you have `rdata` initially set to `NULL` or not, in the second loop iteration `rdata` will either still be `NULL` or be invalid. In the former case, your next `realloc` call will create a new unrelated allocation and the previous one will be leaked and in the latter case you are causing undefined behavior by passing the invalid pointer to `realloc` again.

Additionally, you cannot assign the return value of `realloc` to the same pointer that you passed in, because that may create a memory leak. If `realloc` fails for any reason, it will return a null pointer and if you assign that to the only pointer pointing to the original allocation, then you will have no means left to reach the original allocation (which will still be valid after `realloc` failed).